# How to deploy flask application to cgi-bin folder on shared hosting?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web, hosting

My freelance client is giving FTP access to the shared hosting, I am new to web development and can't figure out how to deploy the flask app to cgi-bin folder, please help me understand how this works?

```
.htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Don't interfere with static files
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/app.cgi/$1 [L]


app.py  file

import sys, subprocess
# implement pip as a subprocess:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 
'flask'])

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello, world"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


app.cgi  file

#!/usr/bin/python3
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from app import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a python script which will contain:

```py
import sys
import subprocess

# implement pip as a subprocess:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 
'flask'])
```

And then follow the instructions given by **Hostgator**.
Please mark it as an answer if it is helpful!

[image: Rajdeep, a Full-Stack Python Developer]

Comment: How to run python from a virtual environment?

Comment: Please read the **Hostgator** Documentation or contact them how to run a python Script.

Comment: Please Refer to The **Hostgator** Documentation or contact them.

Comment: I recommend you to use PythonAnywhere + Hostgator to Deploy your Flask Website. I can write a Answer where I can tell you how to do so. Will I do it ?

Comment: You can join our Slack StackOverFlow Python Channel [here](https://join.slack.com/t/techgeeks-dev/shared_invite/zt-o7h7jd8y-vuRxQSkVp4UdR14RkxQv~w) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the Flask hosting can't be done within Shared-Hosting.
You need **DigitalOcean** or **Heroku** or **PythonAnywhere**(easiest) Hosting to deploy a **Flask**/**Django** Website.

Comment: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/perl-and-python-scripts. It supports python scripts but not flask? I am confused.

Comment: It's rare that a Shared-Hosting provider supports python scripts. But if **Hostgator** does that then do it gives you a console/shell. If yes then run `pip install flask` within it to install **Flask** and you can Deploy your Flask App by setting ```if __name__=="__main__":    app.run()```. If it dosn't have any console/shell then it is impossible to deploy it there.

Comment: I don't have ssh access.

Comment: How to run CGI script to run commands automatically? or run activate the virtual env?

Comment: Please help, I am stuck on it for 3 days.

Comment: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/python-modules  these are the modules which already come with it.

Comment: For CGI you dont actually need any libraries (although [cgi](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html) from standard library is helpful) but I would strongly recommend to use WSGI as not only debugging is much easier with it. There is a [WSGI as CGI adapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler) in the standard library but you can also use [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/) for better performance.

There are microframeworks like Flask/Django which make building sites much easier and they work with WSGI (and therefore CGI).